# How do I change the position of my triangle?

Tags: java, java-8

am trying to do this triangle using 2 arguments.

Can someone help me out and see what is wrong with my code?
I can't seems to flip it to the same as this image.

Thank you!

```
        int width = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int height = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        int starsThisLine = (int) Math.round(width * ((i + 1) / (double) height));
        int dotsBeforeStars = Math.round((width - starsThisLine));

        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            if (j > dotsBeforeStars) {
                System.out.print(".");
            } else if (j < (dotsBeforeStars + starsThisLine)) {
                System.out.print("*");
            } else {
                System.out.println(1);
```

Comment: Remember to look at your post after submitting, and then hitting the edit button and following the proper [markup for post content](/markdown). If you have an image, add that `!` in front of the markdown to actually turn it into an image. And if it's an image of text: do not show images of text. Put the actual text in your post, even if the text is asterisks and periods, with proper code markup.

Comment: How is the triangle supposed to look if the height and width aren't the same? Or should we assume that they are the same

Comment: Sorry. I tried following your guidance, but it says I need at least 10 reputations to post an image. Thanks for your guidance.

Comment: Hi @AnikethMalyala, I am using n by n arguments to fill in height and width.

Comment: @AnikethMalyala with 
int width = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int height = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

Comment: @newwbie I upvoted your post, so now you should have enough reputation to post an image :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it.  Just create a repeat method to return the String with the proper number of characters.

```
int height = 10;
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
   System.out.println(repeat("*", height-i)+repeat(".",i));
}   
    
public static String repeat(String a, int count) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while(count-- > 0) {
        sb.append(a);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Both will print

```
**********
*********.
********..
*******...
******....
*****.....
****......
***.......
**........
*.........
```

One observation. Notice the first line has all stars. But that last line does not have all dots. The same was true in your patterns too.

If you want the start and finish to look like this:
`**********`
`..........`
The loop should be as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= height; i++) {
```

If you want the start and finish to look like this:
`*********.`
`*.........`
The loop should be as follows:

```
for (int i = 1; i < height; i++) {
```

Comment: I tried, but i have errors, it showing error for repeat and string a not found, question: if i key in my arguments in the CLI arguments will it set the triangle according to my arguments?

Comment: Sorry, you can't use the `String.repeat` method as it was introduced in Java 11.  But you can create your own as I showed you.  I do not know why you would get the error message for `String a`.  Make certain that you entered it correctly as it works for me.

Comment: no prob! thanks for the help. the qns was use command line n argument to create n by n triangular pattern. I was thinking is it 2 arguments or do i actually need 1 argument n to create the triangular? sorry im very new to java. I tried the user input with scanner and i tried with using only 1 argument to run the triangular.

Comment: You should just need one.  At as the stars decrease, the dots increase.  So all patterns will look similar only of different sizes.

Comment: thanks sooooo much for clarifying my qns!!! have a good day ahead!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the height and width will always be the same, here is an example implementation that uses a scanner (you can change this if you want to):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int dimensions = scan.nextInt();
    for(int i = 0; i < dimensions; i++){
      for(int dots = 0; dots < i; dots++){
        System.out.print(". ");
      }
      for(int stars = dimensions; stars > i; stars--){
        System.out.print("* ");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```

In this example, our outer for loop with the dimensions represents the code for each row of the triangle, in this case, if we inputted 5, 5 rows.

Then, we start with printing dots since they are on the left side. Since the number of dots goes 0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4, this is equivalent to what "i", or our outer loop counter is.

With the stars, the number of stars goes 5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1, so if we just count backwards from the number of rows to our counter variable, we can get this number.

Comment: I need it to run manually by arguments instead of asking for user input. Therefore I use 
int width = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
int height = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);


but it can't work):

Comment: If you replace the "int dimensions = scan.nextInt();" with "int dimensions = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);", will it work?

Comment: hmmm..i did exactly for what you say but this is for 1 argument. i need it to be star by dot argument. like example i key in 2 arguments manually and both dots and stars will position like the triange image.

Comment: You said that the triangle will always be n by n so why do you need to take in 2 arguments?

Comment: As i will be inputting the CLI arguments in manually like 5 3, and the program will run again to that 2 arguments that i set.
i will post a photo of the CLI argument.

Comment: How would you make a triangle with inputs like 5 3? You said yourself: "Hi @AnikethMalyala, I am using n by n arguments to fill in height and width." 5 3 is not n by n, I'm confused.

Comment: i just post a picture of what I mean by the CLI arguments. I need key in the first number as the height and second number as the width and make it into the triangle image which I post.

Comment: It is unclear why you would need two arguments.  Please edit your question to provide an explanation and what the image would look like if say 4 and 9 were provided as the arguments.